# How to intercept response in ASP.NET 5 after all other middlewares?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my application I need to add a header to almost all responses.

However, middleware won't solve this for me because some other middleware sets a completely fresh response, ends the pipeline and I don't get a look in:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "IsCool");
    return next();
});

app.UseSomeOtherMiddleware(); // This ends the pipeline after removing my `MyHeader`
```

I can't add another middleware after the offending one, because the pipeline is finished.

I could add a `web.config` entry for it:

But as I said, this needs to be added to *almost* all responses. I need just a teeny bit of logic to determine if I add it, and the `web.config` solution doesn't afford me that.

So how can I do this in ASP.NET 5? How can I tap into the pipeline after everything is supposedly finished?

Answer (score 4):

Correct implementation for RC2

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;            
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        context.Response.OnStarting((state) =>
        {
            sw.Stop();
            context.Response.Headers.Add("x-elapsed-time", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString());            
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }, null);

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register a callback with HttpContext.Response.OnStarting and modify the headers just before they are sent.

Comment: This doesn't work for me; the callback is made, but it is not late enough in the pipeline and my headers are lost again

Comment: Not late enough? This is the last event that fires before the headers are sent. The only thing you can do to run later is to register your middleware at the very beginning of the pipeline (OnStarting fires in reverse order of registration). What header are you adding anyways? And why is another component removing it?

Answer (score -1):

I think I solved this by creating a middleware as follows:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);
        context.Response.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "IsCool");
    }
}
```

And using the following in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Don't edit the response headers after calling _next, it will throw if the response body is unbuffered and has already started sending.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that, @Tratcher! I'll try your suggestion instead a bit later this morning :)

Comment: I'm working on the same issue, and was astonished that this was from 2016... and seems to be an solution to an issue that I'm fighting with in DAPR, and the format of the response that it provides... should I be looking at something else in .Net Core >=3.1?